# Navigation-drawer group header - how to set up?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a menu with groups like below. Is that possible to set a headers for each group? I know that's possible for submenus, but what about first level groups?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/main_group">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/leagues_in_progress_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_line_spacing_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_leagues_in_progress" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/last_matches_item"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_alarm_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_last_matches" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/another_group">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/archive_item1"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_archive" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/put_score_item3"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/title_activity_put_score" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each group would be an `item` in your top-level tree. Then just set the `title` attribute for each of these. Using your code it would be like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="First group"
        android:id="@+id/first_group">
        <menu android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/main_group">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/leagues_in_progress_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_format_line_spacing_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_leagues_in_progress" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/last_matches_item"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_alarm_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_last_matches" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:title="Second group"
        android:id="@+id/second_group">
        <menu android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/another_group">

            <item
                android:id="@+id/archive_item1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_open_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_archive" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/put_score_item3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/title_activity_put_score" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Android Studio claims that group element is not allowed in this place.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. It should have been a menu element, not a group element. I just edited my code. Try that.

Comment: This answer is wrong, `android:checkableBehavior` is a property of a `<group>`, not of a `<menu>`.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud that's not a reason to flag it as not-an-answer.

Comment: @Floern why not? This "answer" is fabricated and completely misguiding. It doesn't make any help to the community.

Comment: @TranslucentCloud have a look here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue. The correct action would be to downvote, not to flag.