# Navigation Drawer: Add Titles to Groups, Not Items

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I have a standard Navigation Drawer, pre-created by Android Studio and want to populate it with number of groups. I started with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mode_person"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:title="Person" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_mode_group"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_group_black_24dp"
            android:title="Community" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

But what I didn't get is if it even possible to give each group a title? I mean there is an `android:title` option available for `<item>`s, but it is unavailable for `<group>`s and if I try to wrap groups around items, what I get is a messy entries behavior.

I read through Google's design guideline on Navigation Drawer, but missed the point if groups should have its own names or they should not. Here is a picture of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Is it possible without adding random `<TextView>`s? By the way, I want to do it via XML, not programmatically.

Comment: did u forget picture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation-drawer group header - how to set up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678302/navigation-drawer-group-header-how-to-set-up)

Comment: @TranslucentCloud did you later solve this?

Comment: Nope. Haven't fired up Android Studio for a while, though.

Answer (score 46):

You are right, it's not possible to give groups a title. The only option seems to be to wrap groups into `<item>` and `<menu>` tags like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="General">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:title="Import" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
                    android:title="Gallery" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Resulting in a navigation drawer menu like this

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately things get messy if you try to check some item programmatically at the activity creation time. When setting item pre-checked this way (`Import` for example), if user taps different item (`Gallery`), the first stay checked. User should additionally tap `Import` and `Gallery` multiple times to get first entry unchecked. This is why I rejected this workaround.

Comment: You didn't write about this initially, so no reason to downvote my answer. If the groups `checkableBehavior` does not work for you, then you have to do it programmatically. Check the selected `item` and uncheck all others on Activity creation and on every item click.

Comment: Actually I wrote about it, but not in details: `if I try to wrap groups around items, what I get is a messy entries behavior`. The downvote is legit, since your answer totally ignores this.

Comment: @Saenic This is exactly what I wanted,thanks! My another concern is I want to hide/unhide menu items dynamically,which I achieved with `menuItem.setVisible(true);` .But it is not working for the items which are inside another item, like `Import` in the above example.How do I achieve this ?

Comment: @Neha I had the same problem setting items to visible/invisible. I need to use `findItem()` on the menu instead of iterating through all items (where the nested items are not found).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. It worked perfectly for me in 2021.

Answer (score 16):

You also required to have an outer group with `android:checkableBehavior="single"` so that no two item is selected one from `First Category` and other from `Second Category`. Here is the working code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:title="First Category">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_top"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                android:icon="@drawable/drawable1"
                android:title="Title1" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/id2"
                android:icon="@drawable/drawable2"
                android:title="Title2" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:title="Second Category">
    <menu>
        <group
            android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/id3"
                android:icon="@drawable/drawable3"
                android:title="Title3" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/id4"
                android:icon="@drawable/drawable4"
                android:title="Title4" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
</group>
</menu>
```

Comment: Why is the first category not clickable any more? I used this example, looks pretty nice and is what I exactly was looking for. I have up to four categories in my Navigation Drawer and now only items in one category is clickable. I tried to play with `android:checkableBehavior="single"`, moving, removing and pasting in different places in groups, but no success, only in one category are menu items clickable. Any Ideas? Many thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 6):

Here is well defined how to create menus.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

So in your case create your list in this order item->menu->group. that is to say:

```
 <item android:title="Title">
     <menu>
         <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
             <item android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
                .   .   .
                .   .   .
```

Comment: The same problem I described in the comment to the answer of @Saenic.

Answer (score 1):

For someone out there, that still struggling. Especially on DrawerLayout + Jetpack Navigation. I'm gonna drop my own implementation. After messing up with menu, `NavigationView`, and Jetpack Navigation. Just do a basic setup for Drawer Navigation and use this menu as `NavigationView` menus for 'named group'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <!-- Group for menu item without title -->
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/yourFragment1"
            android:title="Fragment 1"/>
    </group>


    <item android:title="Group 1">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/yourFragment2"
                    android:title="Fragment 2"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/yourFragment3"
                    android:title="Fragment 3"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Group 2">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/yourFragment4"
                    android:title="Fragment 4"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/yourFragment5"
                    android:title="Fragment 5"/>

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/yourFragment6"
                    android:title="Fragment 6"/>
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

You can also add options other than navigating to another fragment, for example for the logout option. Just do like down below.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { dest ->

    if (dest.itemId == R.id.yourMenuIdOfLogoutInMenuXML) {
        logoutUser();
    } else {
        // This will navigate to a corresponding fragments
        NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(dest, navController)

        // drawerLayout is reference to DrawerLayout widget component
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }

    true
}
```

And if you want to check a certain menu programmatically you can just call

```
// navigationView is a reference to your NavigationView component.
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.idOfMenuThatYouWantToCheck)
```

PS. For those of you that don't know how to set up DrawerLayout with Jetpack Navigation please refer to this example [Setup Jetpack Navigation with DrawerLayout](https://medium.com/swlh/android-drawer-layout-with-navigation-components-77253b7d1602).

Answer (score 0):

add xml class `navigation_drawer_title`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="communicate"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and change your `navigationAdapter` like this

```
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0; 
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_TITLE = 3;
    @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View v = null;
            switch (viewType)
            {
                case TYPE_HEADER:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_header, parent, false); //Inflating the layout
                    break;
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_item, parent, false); //Inflating the layout
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_separator, parent, false); //Inflating the layout
                    break;

                case TYPE_TITLE:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_title, parent, false); //Inflating the layout
                    break;
            }
            return new ViewHolder(v, viewType); // Returning the created object

        }
```

and

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        if (navMenuItems.get(position - 1).getItemType() == NavItemType.Group)
            return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        if (navMenuItems.get(position - 2).getItemType() == NavItemType.Group)
            return TYPE_TITLE

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```

Comment: I stated in my question, that I don't want to try to resolve this programmatically.

Comment: i have no idea.i just did it in adapter.